# How to give title to the result of a select query in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

For example I want to do like this:

```
select id,name from first;
```

It should look like this:

```
The Query Result // this should be the title of the query  
id name  
1  Ali  
2  Sami
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you use `psql`, you can change the field separator using `\f` and `\a` meta commands. I show an example below:

```
testdb=# SELECT * FROM first;
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | Ali
  2 | Sami
(2 rows)

testdb=# \f ','
Field separator is ",".

testdb=# \a
Output format is unaligned.

testdb=# SELECT * FROM first;
id,name
1,Ali
2,Sami
(2 rows)
```

And, `\C` meta command can be added any titles.

```
testdb=# \C 'The Query Result'
Title is "The Query Result".

testdb=# SELECT * FROM first;
The Query Result
id,name
1,Ali
2,Sami
(2 rows)
```

Comment: if you run psql with the --csv flag then you can skip \f and \a meta commands. 
`dan@ubuntu:~$ psql  --csv

dan@db=# select * from first;
id,name
1,Ali
2,Sam
`

Answer (score 2):

When using DBeaver, nowadays you can either use --name or --title in front of your SQL statement (closed with ;) to name your SQL query's result tab.

For example:

```
-- title: All active users
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE u.active = 1
ORDER BY u.created_at DESC
```

Just don't forget that you need to use "SQL Editor > Execute statements in separate tabs" for this to work